# Java - make string flag for system.out.format change on input

Tags: java, formatting

I'm trying to set the flag of the

```
System.out.format("%s", string);
```

so the *s* has variable allocated size associated with it.

For example: I want

```
System.out.format("%MyVars", string);
```

Where *MyVar* would be a variable dependent on the size of a particular list in the program

Where as of now I can only have static numbers like:

```
System.out.format("%5s", string);
```

How would I do this?

Comment: How does the size of a list affect the length of the `String` you want to display? Still, the format is also a `String`, so you can change the format on the fly too if you don't hardcode it like that.

Comment: I'm supposed to do something like Dijkstras where I'm supposed to show each step. The steps would keep increasing on each iteration but since the size of the list modifies how many steps there are, i need this size in order to align other columns with it

Comment: Okay, well like I said, the format string is still a String. You could get it from a method for example.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use string concatenation to achieve your desired format?

Below code snippet my help:-

```
int num = 5;
System.out.format("%" + num + "." + string.length() + "S", string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the below snippet:

```
String string = "abc";
int size =5;
System.out.format("%d%s", size, string);
```